# Retornar "bloco" de texto com uma palavra chave a partir de um arquivo txt

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Tenho um arquivo de texto que dentro dele contém cupons segue exemplo de um cupom:

```
                 COTIA CENTRO
                ATACADAO S.A.
               PROF JOSE BARRETO
-----------------------------------------------
CNPJ 00.000.000/0000-00
IE 000.000.000.000
IM ISENTO
-----------------------------------------------
G              Extrato No. 182863Gþ
G        CUPOM FISCAL ELETRâNICO - SATGþ
-----------------------------------------------
#|COD|DESC|QTD|UN|VL UN R$|(VL TR R$)*|VL ITEM 
-----------------------------------------------
001 00071162 AGUA COCO C.JORDAO    1X200ML 
     6 UND9 X 1,49 (1,72)                  8,94
desconto sobre item                       -1,20
002 00001650 COCO SECO TROPIC.       1X1Kg 
 0,828 KG9  X 3,99 (0,73)                  3,30

Total bruto de Itens                      12,24
Total de descontos/acrescimos sobre item  -1,20
GTOTAL R$                                  11,04Gþ

Vale Alimentacao                          11,04

-----------------------------------------------
OBSERVACOES DO CONTRIBUINTE

*Valor aproximado dos tributos do item
Valor aproximado dos tributos deste cupom
(conforme Lei Fed.12.741/2012) R$          2,45
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Federal R$0,47 (4,26%) 
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Estadual R$1,98 (17,93%) 
Fonte: IBPT.
-----------------------------------------------
       CIELO-VEROCARD BENEFICIO
           000000******0000
PDV=75151429 DOC=140068 AUT=938956
VALOR:11,04 S.DISP:1.166,06    (SiTef)
-----------------------------------------------
G              SAT No. 00000000Gþ
            14/06/2021 - 08:27:29

G        0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 Gþ
G          0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 Gþ
CFe35210675315333005925590002843141828638739062|20210614082729|11.04||jf6L4XuLg/T9PyMFRUoWGyqCQZG+YgzerKsDm7GLllv/w6BFvDKIBsRemosUSKyOsDfMkS2Bds+yXqrucQa1zmu2HpVlWxF8qu+M3MB7uMRub5H1NibCZAmQBY7MbXiXQm/0lC4jzG2rnDrmlI19OtJQDgODNDySgTViB3xiQmQVbF/jjM5aLnwZ9wNWReMI4uQHB/Dd3N8w8OVTxEPx7N3p27KGskS/5EmbNc1EX+nhHVNYkOQCzEi5ip0pALN3EzvD/p4b11ThNt697UhM7mRaavjapoEDBBTIrUx1YxOQyWPfeflarB72rePPzpbM9daRvvtkNu7LAxeO/46oOg==
-----------------------------------------------
 TPLinux AT.14.c00N-19.07 - Unisys Brasil Ltda
-----------------------------------------------
4610-CR2 VERSAO:16.05       PDV:002       LJ:059
OPR:000243418Tatiana Lig    14/06/2021 08:27:33
```

Todos os cupons começam com `COTIA CENTRO` e terminam em `OPR:...`

Eu quero fazer uma busca e encontrar um cupom específico com base no número do `Extrato` ou `TOTAL` e caso encontre ele me retorna esse cupom.

Eu tentei usando Regex:

```
$caminho = 'arqEspelho.txt';

$espelho = file_get_contents ($caminho);

$re = '/(?=\s{17}COTIA CENTRO).+?(.+?OPR:.\d+\w+\s\w+\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/s';

preg_match_all($re, $espelho, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
```

Porém ele retorna em Multi Array e não sei como fazer essa busca
Como eu poderia executar essa busca?
Teria alguma maneira mais fácil de separar os cupons para efetuar a busca?

Answer (score 0):

Regex provavelmente não é a melhor opção. Talvez seja melhor ir lendo o arquivo linha a linha, e para cada linha você vê se está no início ou fim de um cupom, ou se tem extrato naquela linha, etc:

```php
$cupons = [];
$texto_cupom = '';
$handle = fopen("arqEspelho.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    // lê as linhas do arquivo
    while (($linha = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $linha;
        $texto_cupom .= $linha;
        if (strpos($linha, 'COTIA CENTRO') !== false) {
            // começa um novo cupom
            $texto_cupom = '';
            $cupom = [];
        } else if (preg_match('/Extrato No. (\d+)/', $linha, $m)) {
            $cupom['extrato'] = $m[1];
        } else if (preg_match('/TOTAL R\$\s+(\d+,\d{2})/', $linha, $m)) {
            $cupom['total'] = $m[1];
        } else if (strpos($linha, 'OPR:') === 0) {
            // fim do cupom, salva o texto atual e adiciona no array de cupons
            $cupom['texto'] = $texto_cupom;
            $cupons[] = $cupom;
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // erro ao abrir o arquivo
}
```

Assim, `$cupons` será um array contendo outros arrays (e cada um desses arrays internos tem os dados de um cupom). Para buscar nesse array, fica fácil:

```php
foreach($cupons as $cupom) {
    if ($cupom['extrato'] == '123') {
        // achou extrato 123, imprime o total e o texto do cupom
        echo $cupom['total'], $cupom['texto'];
    }
}
```

Eu só usei regex para pegar o extrato e o total, ficando bem mais simples. As informações que quero estão entre parênteses, o que forma [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que posso pegar depois (usando `$m[1]` - o primeiro grupo, já que é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex).

---

Com uma única regex, fica bem mais complicado:

```
$caminho = 'arqEspelho.txt';
$espelho = file_get_contents($caminho);

$re = '/^ +COTIA CENTRO(?:.*\n)+?.+Extrato No. (\d+)(?:.*\n)+?.+TOTAL R\$ +(\d+,\d{2})(?:.*\n)+?^OPR:.+$/m';
if (preg_match_all($re, $espelho, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($matches as $m) {
        list($cupom, $extrato, $total) = $m;
        // $cupom tem todo o texto do cupom, $extrato e $total tem os respectivos valores
    }
}
```

Eu uso várias vezes `(?:.*\n)+?` (zero ou mais caracteres, seguidos de uma quebra de linha, tudo isso repetido várias vezes), para pular as linhas que não me interessam. Também uso o quantificador *lazy* `+?`, para evitar que ele vá até o final do arquivo e acabe achando que todos os cupons são uma coisa só (entenda melhor o quantificador *lazy* lendo [aqui](/q/415757/112052) e [aqui](/a/401755/112052)).

E uso o [modificador](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `m`, para que os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` indiquem o início e fim de uma linha (sem o `m`, eles pegam somente o início e fim da string).

Então a regex pega tudo desde "COTIA CENTRO", passando pelo extrato e pelo total (também usando grupos de captura para pegar esses dados), e termina no "OPR".

Depois basta iterar pelo array de `$matches` e pegar as informações, aí você faz o que precisar com elas.

Mas eu ainda prefiro ler o arquivo linha a linha, como na primeira solução acima. Não só a regex fica mais simples de entender e manter, como também o array final fica - na minha opinião - mais organizado. Claro que você também consegue montar o mesmo array usando a regex acima, mas o fato de ter uma expressão muito complicada já faz com que não valha a pena.

Comment: Usando este arquivo [link](https://pastebin.com/RGzQWkC1) como exemplo, quando vou buscar o cupom tanto pelo extrato(182862) como pelo valor(66,81), ele está retornando o mesmo cupom duas vezes e na segunda vez o cupom está vindo itens a mais até a segunda via.
Exemplo - 1º Cupom [link](https://pastebin.com/t3sdZwaV)
Exemplo - 2º Cupom [link](https://pastebin.com/85Pmve5b)

Comment: @LeandroPio O problema é que [nesse arquivo](https://pastebin.com/RGzQWkC1) os cupons tem a linha OPR, depois tem uma linha com "abobrinha", depois tem várias outras linhas e outro OPR. Ou seja, ele termina o primeiro cupom, mas antes de começar outro (ou seja, antes de encontrar "COTIA CENTRO"), ele encontra outro final (outro "OPR"). Se um cupom pode ter mais de um OPR, aí tem que mudar o código. Mas se cada cupom só pode ter um OPR, então o arquivo está errado

Comment: Entendi, é que aquilo seria a segunda via do comprovante, teria que terminar o cupom assim que encontrasse o primeiro OPR correto? Como eu poderia fazer isso? No mais muito obrigado pela grande ajuda

Comment: @LeandroPio Provavelmente teria que ter mais uma variável de controle (tipo `$encontrei_opr`) que indica se vc já encontrou o OPR e ainda não chegou outro cupom. E ai vc ignora a segunda via, por exemplo...